# Transforming array to JSON - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am going to get results from database like this.

```
 array(
         [0] => array( 
                       [type]   => orange,
                       [number] => 10,
                       [size]   => 10c,
                       [weight] => 1l
                     ) 
         [1] => array( 
                       [type]   => mango,
                       [number] => 10,
                       [size]   => 10c,
                       [weight] => 1l
                     ) 
         [1] => array( 
                       [type]   => apple,
                       [number] => 10,
                       [size]   => 10c,
                       [weight] => 1l
                     ) 
         [3] => array( 
                       [type]   => mango,
                       [number] => 10,
                       [size]   => 10c,
                       [weight] => 1l
                     ) 

     )
```

Basically, I need to convert this to the following JSON Format:

```
         "mango" : [{ 
                       "number" : "10",
                       "size"   : "10c",
                       "weight" : "1l"
                     },
                     { 
                       "number" : "12",
                       "size"   : "14c",
                       "weight" : "12"
                     }
                   ],
         "orange" : [{ 
                       "number" : "12",
                       "size"   : "10c",
                       "weight" : "1l"
                     },
                     { 
                       "number" : "12",
                       "size"   : "14c",
                       "weight" : "11"
                     }
                   ],
         "apple" : [{ 
                       "number" : "10",
                       "size"   : "10c",
                       "weight" : "1l"
                     },
                     { 
                   ]
```

Ignore the number, size and weight. Those are just random numbers.
But the first element in the array contains the JSON tag. That should be removed from the array, but taken as tag for array of objects in JSON (you can see that).

I know we can write with loops, conditions, etc.  Is there a smart and quick way to do this with existing built in php functions with less looping and conditions?

I guess, these are the steps:

1. Filter the arrays individuality based on type. Probably, 3 times here to get the 3 fruits. Which function would help here? Filter based on Value. Or ideally key value pair.
2. You get 3 arrays, each for one type of fruit. Pop off the type element in all arrays individually.
3. Loop through the types, and put the arrays in each type, with type value as index.

Any other better ways?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You can use existing PHP functions but you are no doubt going to have to loop through the results at least once on your own to build this out. AFAIK there is no method in PHP that's going to accomplish this for you

Comment: You're gonna need some loops...

Comment: You're looking to drastically restructure the array before encoding it. This is called **programming**, and there is no built-in function to do programming for you.

Comment: No, such a *magic* function does not exist. Use loops, conditions etc to change the array structure to the desired, and the use json_encode.

Comment: I am certainly aware of the fact there its not going to be possible without looping. But I am trying to do with less steps as possible.

Comment: @KevinRave The first step in optimizing your code is to *have some code to optimize*. If you haven't tried anything yet, what can we help you with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restructure your old array to a new one like this :

```
$new = array();
foreach($old as $vec){
    $new[$vec['type']] = array(
        'number' => $vec['number'],
        'size' => $vec['size'],
        'weight' => $vec['weight']      
    );
}
echo json_encode($new);
```

Comment: @alpera. Lol! 2nd Mango..Anyways, Probably the array will have only one array of each type. But I get the idea. We can write addition step to add instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Change array structure as you need first and then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: This is a simple re-wording of his question, with a link to the docs. Not very useful as an answer...