# make an array to string JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_1","project_id":"6b9d7206"}
    [1] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_6","project_id":"896fb06f"}
    [2] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_8","project_id":"90f33ff3"}
    [3] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_9","project_id":"ca43eaff"}
    [4] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_13","project_id":"9c2eeee1"}
    [5] => {"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_14","project_id":"57cf900e"} 
)
```

**how to make this into a string like following**

```
{"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_1","project_id":"6b9d7206"}
{"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_6","project_id":"896fb06f"}
{"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_8","project_id":"90f33ff3"}
{"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_9","project_id":"ca43eaff"}
{"vpg_id":"2","profile_id":"WEBCEO_14","project_id":"57cf900e"}
```

**using JSON** **and PHP**

Comment: `implode` on `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transforming array to JSON - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011748/transforming-array-to-json-php)

Comment: Use the `json_encode` method!

Answer (score 0):

use php's function json_encode :

```
json_encode($array)
```

or implode it with new-line :

```
implode("\n", $array);
```

Answer (score -1):

check -> [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
use

```
json_encode($array);
```